# UIButton Adjust View Height Based on Title (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to figure out how to resize the height of my `UIButton` frame so that it will match the height of its `TitleLabel` contents at a given width. I'm currently performing this at `viewDidAppear`.

I've attempted to do this via `NSLayoutConstraint` with something like the following:

```
let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: button.titleForState(.Normal)!)
let rect = attributeString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

var heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: button, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: rect.height)
```

and by setting the `frame` of the `UIButton` directly using the `rect` calculated above:

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, rect.height)
```

But, I'm unable to affect the height of the buttons' views.  The only way I've serendipitously been able to change the height has been by fiddling with the `multiplier` property of `NSLayoutConstraint`, but it is changing the height unpredictably.

Does anyone know how to do this?

### EDIT

I should add that the text is wrapping successfully via `NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping`.  Here is my full button construction:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton
button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0svS.png

Comment: Have you tried setting lineNumber to 0?

Comment: @Aggressor Yes I have. Just tried it again and no effect.

Comment: Editing frames and having constraints is a dicey business. Whenever a view refreshes it will override your frames in order to set constraints. I suspect you have a constraint restricting your button. Try removing the button from the interface builder and create it programmatically in the viewDidAppear block.

Comment: Your other option is to change the constraints on the button via code

Comment: @Aggressor I'm actually not using Interface Builder for this.  All views and constraints are programmatically generated. The height constraint I pasted in my question above doesn't seem to have any effect except for when the `multiplier` is changed.  I was hoping I would be able to vary the height with the `constant` property of that constraint, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any good "automatic" way to do this. The way that worked for me, was to override setTitle:forState: in a UIButton subclass, and calculate the size of the text there to use for adjusting a height constraint. The button had a height constraint (with IBOutlet heightCon) , and also a width constraint set in IB (you could add these in code if you're not using IB)

```
override func setTitle(title: String?, forState state: UIControlState) {
        super.setTitle(title, forState: state)
        let attributeString = NSAttributedString(string: currentTitle!, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: titleLabel!.font])
        let rect = attributeString.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.frame.width, CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
        heightCon.constant = rect.size.height + titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is also the solution I eventually arrived at.